# How to batch-copy the 10 newest files to a directory in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I use the following script to keep only the newest 360 files (a year, daily-made backup) in the directory:

```
for /f "skip=360 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d *.*') do @del "%%F"
```

How to afterwards copy the newest 7 files to another directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Three alternatives

    rem Pure arithmetics
    set "numFiles=7"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d') do (
        2>nul set /a "1/numFiles", "numFiles-=!!numFiles" && (
            echo copy "%%~fa" x:\somewehere
        )
    )

    rem Pure arithmetics 2 - No negation operator
    set "numFiles=7"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d') do (
        2>nul set /a "1/numFiles", "numFiles-=1" && (
            echo copy "%%~fa" x:\somewehere
        )
    )

    rem Number list of files
    set "numFiles=7"
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('
        dir /b /o-d /a-d
        ^| findstr /n "^"
    ') do if %%a leq %numFiles% (
        echo copy "%%~fb" x:\somewehere
    )
```

Comment: You did  `disabledelayedexpansion`, but it is to mention that the arithmetic solution does require this to have the double not operator working `!!`

Comment: @LotPings, Sorry, I misunderstood you. You are right, but that is one of the reasons I almost always include the `setlocal` defining the context under the code works. Also, keeping delayed expansion disabled except when really required is one of my bad habits.